# Apply function to data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas, function

In the following codes, I try to define a function first and apply the function to a dataframe to reset the geozone.

```
import pandas as pd
testdata ={'country': ['USA','AUT','CHE','ABC'], 'geozone':[0,0,0,0]}
d =pd.DataFrame.from_dict(testdata, orient = 'columns')
    
def setgeozone(dataframe, dcountry, dgeozone):
    dataframe.loc[dataframe['dcountry'].isin(['USA','CAN']),'dgeozone'] =1
    dataframe.loc[dataframe['dcountry'].isin(['AUT','BEL']),'dgeozone'] =2
    dataframe.loc[dataframe['dcountry'].isin(['CHE','DNK']),'dgeozone'] =3
        
setgeozone(d, country, geozone)
```

I got error message saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-56-98dad4781f73>", line 1, in <module>
    setgeozone(d, country, geozone)

NameError: name 'country' is not defined
```

Can someone help me understand what I did wrong.

Many thanks.

Comment: The column in your dataframe is `country`, but the access in the function is `dcountry`. One of these is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass parameters other than the DataFrame itself to your function. Try this:

```
def setgeozone(df):
    df.loc[df['country'].isin(['USA','CAN']),'geozone'] = 1
    df.loc[df['country'].isin(['AUT','BEL']),'geozone'] = 2
    df.loc[df['country'].isin(['CHE','DNK']),'geozone'] = 3

setgeozone(df)
```

Here's two other (also better) ways to accomplish what you need:

1. Use `map`:

```
df["geozone"] = df["country"].map({"USA": 1, "CAN": 1, "AUT": 2, "BEL": 2, "CHE": 3, "DNK": 3})
```

2. Use `numpy.select`:

```
import numpy as np
df["geozone"] = np.select([df["country"].isin(["USA", "CAN"]), df["country"].isin(["AUT", "BEL"]), df["country"].isin(["CHE", "DNK"])], 
                          [1, 2, 3])
```